# Specific-length vertical padding in table (with text wrapping, alternating row colors, and specified widths)

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, rowcolor, cellspace

I'm trying to create fixed-width (i.e. spanning the whole `\textwidth`) tables, with alternating row colors and arbitrary alignments (horizontal and vertical), that have evenly-spaced specific-length (i.e. I can specify an absolute length) vertical padding on the rows.

To begin, a MWE (it does have quite a lot of features, I suppose, but they should all represent something I need in the final result):

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\rowcolors{1}{}{mycolor}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\the\textwidth-1cm-4\tabcolsep\relax}}
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
1 & \lipsum*[66] \\
2 & \lipsum*[75] \\
3 & \lipsum*[66] \\
4 & \lipsum*[75]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Initial attempt]

So, I can specify the table widths, color the rows, and justify/align the text. All is good so far. Now I would like to add the vertical spacing.

I've tried a few combinations already:

- `\arraystretch`, produces uneven vertical padding when used with `p`/`m`/etc column types.
- `booktabs` doesn't play well with the row colors, as the increased vertical spacing isn't colored (and any solutions I've seen are best suited to coloring single rows, not alternating rows - i.e. by redefining the behaviour above and below the `\midrule` command)

My hope is that I can get `cellspace` to work, but when I include the following code:

```
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{10pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{10pt}

[...]

\begin{tabular}{S{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
    S{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\the\textwidth-1cm-4\tabcolsep\relax}}}
```

I get the following:

[image: Overflow problem]

Where the text isn't wrapping properly, but the resulting lines are evenly spaced (and the row colors are the correct width, actually).

Any help on getting the `cellspace` padding to work with text-wrapped lines would be greatly appreciated.

- Ideally I would like to avoid importing dozens of libraries (they're already giving me a headache in the full document), but I understand this may be unavoidable.
- I would also prefer an extensible solution (i.e. one where I don't have to add code to every row of the table), as my document has a large number of these tables.
- And if the solution worked with `\multicolumn`, that would be sweet.

**P.S.** I've been trying to make this work with `tabularx` so far, and I very much enjoy the convenience of combining `X` and `c` columns, so if your solution involves `tabularx`, that would be nice. I didn't include it because I wanted to avoid overcomplicating matters with lots of packages. However, the error in tabularx does seem to be the same (i.e. the absence of text-wrapping when using `cellspace` columns).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try with `tabularx` (which would  use a simpler code)?

Comment: Why hello. Yes, I did, as I mentioned in the PS down the bottom. However, I ran into exactly the same problems.

Comment: However, I can edit the question to use tabularx, if it would simplify matters? (I was worried it would complicate them)

Comment: Never mind, I worked with your initial code and modified it so that it works, and added some improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>{...]` should be outside the  `S` pre-column specifier. Herer is a simple code with `tabularx`.

I also took the liberty to change your definition of `mycolor` to a nicer one (for my taste). Of course, feel free to return to your initial version if you preferit.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{mycolor}{Gainsboro!70!Lavender}%
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{10pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{10pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{mycolor}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Sc >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}S{X}}
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
1 & \lipsum*[66] \\
2 & \lipsum*[75] \\
3 & \lipsum*[66] \\
4 & \lipsum*[75]
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I'm having a little troubling reproducing your image, though. When I copy-paste your LaTeX into Overleaf (I tried it with all compilers, just in case, but I'm primarily using XeLaTeX) I only get spacing at the top of the cells - with the exception of the first row, which also has bottom spacing. Do you have any additional setup I'm missing?

Comment: I only used what I posted. To be sure, I've just compiled with `xelatex`, which gives the same result. Did you compile exactly the code I posted, and nothing more?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. Which is confusing. Overleaf example project: https://v2.overleaf.com/read/sqwvdhmkxbsc

Comment: Could you check the version of cell space which is used? Mine is 1.8.1 (19/03/2019).

Comment: Yep, that was it. Overleaf has v1.6 (2009/07/31) - lord knows why. Thank you so much! (tested with manually uploaded v1.8 and all was well)

Comment: Well, cellspace had several updates these last years, and probably it has not high priority on Overleaf.